# ManyToMany relation - downloading data in JSON

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a ManyToMany relation between tables:

- User
- Tag

(Everything is done according to the recommendations)

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Users
        .Include(x => x.UserTags)
            .ThenInclude(z => z.Tag);
}
```

The application is very deep

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Jon",
        "password": null,
        "userTags": [
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "user": {
                 ...
```

I would like to get:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Bartek",
        "password": null,
        "userTags": [ // List of Tags ]
```

**EDITED**

At the moment I have done as below

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var users = _userService.GetAll();

    List<UserDto> result = new List<UserDto>();

    foreach (var user in users)
    {
        var tagDto = _mapper.Map<IList<TagDto>>(user.UserTags.Select(x => x.Tag));

        var userDtos = new UserDto
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            Username = user.Username,
            Tags = tagDto
        };
        result.Add(userDtos);
    }

    return Ok(result);
}
```

But is not there any built-in option to get the intended effect?

Answer (score 1):

I built my own Mapper for this situation:

```
public class MyMapper
{
    public IList<UserDto> GetUserDto(IEnumerable<User> users, IMapper _mapper)
    {
        List<UserDto> result = new List<UserDto>();

        foreach (var user in users)
        {
            var tagDto = _mapper.Map<IList<TagDto>>(user.UserTags.Select(x => x.Tag));

            var userDtos = new UserDto
            {
                Id = user.Id,
                Username = user.Username,
                Tags = tagDto
            };
            result.Add(userDtos);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Use: (Controller)

```
private IMapper _mapper;
private MyMapper _myMapper;

public UsersController(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
    _curioMapper = new CurioMapper();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAll()
{
    var users = _userService.GetAll();
    var result = _myMapper.GetUserDto(users, _mapper);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, assuming "Everything is done according to the recommendations"

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Users
        .Include(x => x.UserTags)
            .ThenInclude(z => z.Tag);
}
```

this data appears to indicate

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "username": "Bartek",
        "password": null,
        "userTags": [ // List of Tags ]
```

that you should change to this

```
public IEnumerable<User> GetAll()
{
    return _context.Users
        .Include(a => a.UserTags.Tags.Select(c => c.tagname));
}
```